# Refined bitwise division algorithm in MIPS

Tags: algorithm, assembly, bit-manipulation, mips, integer-division

Our assignment is to implement a refined bitwise division algorithm in MIPS.

Basically in the refined program, we load the dividend into the LO bits of the 64 bit register and the remainder will accumulate in the HI bits, which are originally all set to 0.

Then we simply test if HI (our remainder) > = divisor. 
If our accumulating remainder is not currently > = divisor, we simply left shift the entire register and fill in with a 0. This is the beginning of our quotient. As the dividend bits move into HI, we will finally have a situation where HI > =
divisor. Then we will subtract the divisor from HI, shift the entire register left, and fill in with a 1.

In short, we can simply continue to shift all 64 bits left, filling in with a 0 when HI < divisor, subtracting the divisor from HI and filling in with a 1 when HI > = divisor.

In our homework, we are to write a program to accept two positive numbers (16 bit signed numbers) from the console, divide the former by the latter.

I put the divisor in $t0, the remainder in $t3, and the dividend in $t2. $t3 and $t2 are both 16 bits, and together they pair up to be a 32-bit register. Somehow, my program returns a really funky quotient: the least significant few bits are correct, but the most significant is always 1; somehow I can't get rid of the 1, no matter how many bits I shift left. For instance, if the dividend is 1000, by shifting left, instead of getting 0001 0000, I actually get 10000 - MSB is always 1. Could someone please take a look at my program and give me some suggestions? Thanks a lot!

```
.data
GETA:           .asciiz "Enter Dividend: "
GETB:           .asciiz "Enter Divisor: "
QT:           .asciiz "Quotient = "
RM:           .asciiz "Remainder = "
NL:             .asciiz "\n"

.text
main:
li $v0, 4             #Prompt for a dividend               
la $a0, GETA                           
syscall                                     

li $v0, 5             #Read dividend from user                   
syscall                              
move $t2, $v0         #dividend in $t2

li $v0, 4             #Prompt for a divisor        
la $a0, GETB                         
syscall     

li $v0, 5             #Read divisor from user                       
syscall                               
move $t0, $v0         #divisor in $t0                   

addi $t4, $zero, 17   #counter
j Loop

Loop:
slt $t1, $t3, $t0     #if remainder < divisor, $t1=1
beq $t1, $zero, subroutine   #remainder >= divisor, $t1=0

#if remainder < divisor
sll $t3, $t3, 1       #shift remainder by to left by 1

andi $t5, $t2, 32768    #get MSB of $t2
bne $zero, $t5, updateRemainder1   #MSB of $t2 is 1
#MSB of $t2 is 0
sll $t2, $t2, 1       #shift dividend to left by 1

addi $t4, $t4, -1     #decrease counter by 1
bne $zero, $t4, Loop
j Exit

subroutine:
sub $t3, $t3, $t0     #subtract divisor from remainder
sll $t3, $t3, 1       #shift remainder by to left by 1

andi $t5, $t2, 32768    #get MSB of $t2
bne $zero, $t5, updateRemainder2   #MSB of $t2 is 1
#MSB of $t2 is 0
sll $t2, $t2, 1       #shift dividend to left by 1
ori $t2, $t2, 1       #fill in LSB of $t2 with a 1

addi $t4, $t4, -1     #decrease counter by 1
bne $zero, $t4, Loop
j Exit

updateRemainder1:
ori $t3, $t3, 1       #set LSB of remainder to 1
sll $t2, $t2, 1       #shift dividend to left by 1  

addi $t4, $t4, -1     #decrease counter by 1
bne $zero, $t4, Loop
j Exit

updateRemainder2:
ori $t3, $t3, 1       #set LSB of remainder to 1
sll $t2, $t2, 1       #shift dividend to left by 1
ori $t2, $t2, 1       #fill in LSB of $t2 with a 1  

addi $t4, $t4, -1     #decrease counter by 1
bne $zero, $t4, Loop
j Exit

Exit:
sub $t2, $t2, 524288
li $v0, 4            #print out output line
la $a0, QT
syscall

li $v0, 1            #print out quotient
move $a0, $t2
syscall

li $v0, 4            #print out new line
la $a0, NL
syscall

li $v0, 4            #print out output line
la $a0, RM
syscall

li $v0, 1            #print out remainder
move $a0, $t3
syscall

li $v0, 10                       
syscall
```

Comment: Note that mips registers are 32 bit, not 16.  Is that the source of your problem?

Comment: I just fixed the problem! It seems to be the counter I'm using. But anyway thank you!